# Use sys.dm_tran_session_transactions for active transaction information

Tags: sql-server

I am reading this SQL Server DBA book and just couldn't figure this out:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
GO
USE AdventureWorks2014;
GO
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Department
INSERT INTO HumanResources.Department (Name, GroupName)
VALUES ('Test', 'QA');

SELECT session_id, transaction_id, is_user_transaction, is_local
FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
WHERE is_user_transaction = 1;
GO
```

-- Got sessions_id 52

```
SELECT s.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) s
WHERE c.most_recent_session_id = 52
GO
```

-- Here, I got "select @@trancount" instead of the select and insert queries

-- I reran the query without specifying session_id

```
SELECT s.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) s
```

and didn't see the select and insert queries at all:

```
use [master]
select @@trancount
SELECT s.text  FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) s
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Try running the first query in one window/tab, and the second and third in a different window/tab.